# Could trying to disable WindowsServer.plist break my iMac it will no longer start?

Tags: mac, startup, macos

Forgive the long story, but I have a mix of old knowledge and unfamiliarity with Mac so I don't know what might be relevant. The tldr version is my iMac won't boot.

---

Trying to put op an upnp server: Windows Server on my Leopard Imac I found afterwards that the service planted itself. Trying to quit the process, immediately triggered a sort of reboot screen, and the OS responded, but still the service was not quitted.

I tried (I'm a former Win user, and not acquianted with unix - I picked up the command from a forum) with a sudo launchcntl -w to disable the service.
By doing this, the mac spinning wheel appeared and nothing responded anymore.

I powered down the Imac. When trying to restart the boot reached the gray apple logo screen with the spinning wheel still there, as if it was still trying to disable WindowsServer. The keyboard locked immediately and caps light on.

Tried SMC reset, pram reset. As the keyboard was locked each time I tried, no luck. Now, the power button only responds when I first detach the power chord, and reattach it. Inserting the 1st install disk trying to boot from it and run diagnostics didn't work. Always the same screen with the spinning wheel, no keyboard response. DVD is even locked, and cannot eject it anymore.

Safe boot of course doesn't work as not one keyboard is accepted.

So, I'm dead locked on all sides. Must admit that windows still gave you a chance to boot. This mac is dead on a service disablement process.
The damn keyboard locks, so I have no control. I whished there was a reset button like on the TC.

What to do ? I have no idea. Backup is not available on Time Machine.

Does this need hardware repair or does someone have any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a mess - but you could do one test to isolate the hardware from the software (and some of the hardware).

Power off the Mac and pull the power cord. Disconnect **everything** you can - keyboard, mouse, etc... Take out all RAM - the manuals are at http://support.apple.com/manuals if you are not familiar with the safety precautions and tools needed.

Then plug in only the power cord and wait a few seconds. If the Mac doesn't start up, press the power button once.

- You should get three beeps if the machine is healthy.
- Power it off and put the RAM back in - be sure it's seated well / pushed in completely.
- Connect only the mouse and power it on holding the mouse button down (button one if there are several).
- The CD should come out if the hardware is healthy.
- Shut it down (you can use the mouse or connect a keyboard if needed).
- Now power on with the shift key held.

At this point, if your Mac booted, it's likely everything is fine and you can use Apple's support to troubleshoot the startup issue. If anything doesn't go like I mentioned - you should take a printout of this and what your results were and post here, or seek hardware help.

Comment: I managed to get the dvd install disk 1 out in the mean time with a tip from another forum. Holding left button mouse and push eject. It worked.But I gues this will not get me further . I expected an answer without having to pull out hardware. But I understand. I see no screws on the back. But I can have a look.

Comment: Feel free to skip the RAM pulling and assume it passes. If that step fails - you won't get past others either. Maybe I should make an edit to the answer...

Comment: I'm dutch speaking, so I don't follow you. The manuals link does not include the Imac. I disabled beeps, because I didn't like the start up sounds all the time. Sorry.

Comment: I can only power on when first detaching the chord, placing it back, and the I can power on. Followed your steps. No result.

Comment: Managed to pull out the ram, and followed your steps. But at boot I heard more than 3 beeps, it repeated beeping. I shut down.  Same problem. It's worse I guess ? No ?

Comment: So without the RAM - do you get three beeps?

Comment: As I explained, without ram he goes beyond 10 beeps and keeps on beeping. Problem remains. Also at the beginning of the problem I still could access the shared folders on the imac from the macbook i'm using now. This doesn't work anymore either, despite linking both macs with an ethernet cable.

Comment: Thanks for keeping up with me. After a couple of minutes, the mac goes down automatically.

Comment: Can I still do something myself you think, or do I need to take it to a repair centre ? The only thing I can think of is firewire connect the macbook and the imac. Is this worth buying the cable. At least it could help me recover the shared folders on the Imac, or not ? Then I think I would dispose of the Imac, and go on working with my macbook. What would you do, also considering it's a 2008 model ?